# How to expose a variable in app.vue globally in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, global-variables

I am using vuejs to develop a module of my application, i will be getting data which i need to set to a variable ex this.gblData in the App.vue.

I will build the vue application and integrating it into a another application. Is there a way to expose the variable gblData in the parent application.

Comment: How do you instantiate your `App`? Just store the instance in a global variable and access its `.gblData` property there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can pass this variable thhrough `window` object:

```
// set
window.gblData = "something";
// get
console.log(window.gblData);
```

Comment: I don't know if it's really a good behavior to use a global variable with window.something. The simple reason for avoiding global variables at all costs is that you can never be sure which other scripts get loaded at the same time. So there are chances to make some conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1: Create a global variable**

```
const gblData = "something";
```

expose your global variable:

```
new Vue({
    data:{
        gblData
    }
})
```

**Option2: Define global variable in the prototype.**

```
Vue.prototype.$gblData = "something";
```

you can now use this variable in any vue component like this:

```
console.log(this.$gblData);
```

Comment: Highly recommend option 1 + vue provide/inject api for child components depending on that data.  Option 2 is no-good.  You shouldn't manipulate Vue's prototype directly as there could be unexpected behavior now or later, better to use Vue.extend() to create a subclass of Vue, manipulate that prototype/add in data, and then use that subclass for your app.

Answer (score 0):

in [vue3](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties):

```js
// Vue3

const app = Vue.createApp({})
app.config.globalProperties.gblData = 'something'


app.component('a-child-component', {
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.gblData) // 'something'
  }
})
```